# Flask, SAP UI5 and MVC

Tags: python, model-view-controller, flask, sapui5

I want to build a Python-Flask Application and use SAPUI5.
I tried to build this small Application in Flask: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.60.1/#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.05/preview

Everything worked well and my code looks like this:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SAPUI5 Walkthrough</title>
    <script
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="/static/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-preload="async"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "static": "./"
        }'
        >
    </script>
    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.xmlview({
                viewName: "mvc.view.App"
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

**App.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="mvc.controller.App"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Button
        text="Say Hello"
        press="onShowHello"/>
</mvc:View>
```

**App.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("mvc.App", {

        onShowHello : function () {
            // show a native JavaScript alert
            /* eslint-disable no-alert */
            alert("Hello World");
            /* eslint-enable no-alert */
        }
    });

});
```

**My question now is**: How can I pass parameters from my app.py to the App.view.xml and App.controller.js?

At the end I want to achieve something like this:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html", text="Hello World", buttonlabel="Say Hello")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**App.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="mvc.controller.App"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Button
        text="{{ buttonlabel }}"
        press="onShowHello"/>
</mvc:View>
```

**App.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("mvc.App", {

        onShowHello : function () {
            // show a native JavaScript alert
            /* eslint-disable no-alert */
            alert({{ text }});
            /* eslint-enable no-alert */
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: UI5 is not a template engine

Long Answer: An UI5 app is composed by static files (.js, .html, .css). So your python server has to return them to the client as they are.

Any communication from your UI5 app and your python server needs to be done via REST calls.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create routes for the files you want to enhance with parameters,
then you can pass values to the templating engine.

```
@app.route('/views/App.view.xml')
def render_view_app():
    return render_template("/views/App.view.xml", buttonlabel="Say Hello")

@app.route('/controller/App.controller.js')
def render_controller_app():
    return render_template("/controller/App.controller.js", text="Hello World")
```

This approach however is **highly** inneficient. You will face a lot of problems going forward. Minor changes will take way too much time because of dependencies to other views and eventually you have to figure out how to handle data state (e.g. multiple users editing the same data).

SAPUI5 has plenty of tools for that! Therefore it is advised to figure out a database model for your views, which contains all the values, properties, attributes you need to render your sapui5 components.

After that, you build a browser application that handles database requests via REST/oData, or any protocol of your choice, and builds your UI according to the data.